# Weight Paint x mirror is painting left and right weight to the left side of the mesh

Tags: weight-painting, mirror

Im trying to paint weight on the left side of the mesh and have it mirror over while painting to the opposing bones on the opposite side (def-thigh.L over to def-thigh.R). however, when I paint, it paints weight for the left and right bones to the same side verts (def-thigh.L). instead of mirroring the weight over to the verts for bone def-thigh.R.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under options, uncheck "topology mirror"